# Can't access Windows 10 Software RAID0 Disk from Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, windows, raid, windows-10

I have Windows 10 and Ubuntu 16.04 installed on a SSD. I created RAID0 (I think it is called striped volume) via Windows Disk Manager with 2 x 1TB HDDs. I wanna access this partition from Ubuntu.

I tried some methods including ldmtool and mdadm but I couldn't find any methods to access my disks from Ubuntu. I'm open to any suggestion possible :) I can give any output if it will be useful for solution

Here is ldmtool solution I found online

```
enes@emma:/dev/mapper$ sudo ldmtool create all
[
]
```

And here is some output from mdadm solution I found online

```
enes@emma:/dev/mapper$ sudo mdadm --build /dev/dm-0 --chunk=64 --level=0 --raid-devices=2 /dev/sda1 /dev/sdc1
mdadm: device /dev/dm-0 exists but is not an md array.

enes@emma:/dev/mapper$ sudo mdadm --build /dev/md0 --chunk=64 --level=0 --raid-devices=2 /dev/sda1 /dev/sdc1
mdadm: Cannot open /dev/sda1: Device or resource busy

enes@emma:/dev$ sudo mdadm -v --assemble --scan
mdadm: looking for devices for further assembly
mdadm: Cannot assemble mbr metadata on /dev/dm-0
mdadm: Cannot assemble mbr metadata on /dev/sdf1
mdadm: Cannot assemble mbr metadata on /dev/sdf
mdadm: Cannot assemble mbr metadata on /dev/sde1
mdadm: Cannot assemble mbr metadata on /dev/sde
mdadm: Cannot assemble mbr metadata on /dev/sdd1
mdadm: Cannot assemble mbr metadata on /dev/sdd
mdadm: no recogniseable superblock on /dev/sdc1
mdadm: Cannot assemble mbr metadata on /dev/sdc
mdadm: no recogniseable superblock on /dev/sdb4
mdadm: Cannot assemble mbr metadata on /dev/sdb3
mdadm: Cannot assemble mbr metadata on /dev/sdb2
mdadm: Cannot assemble mbr metadata on /dev/sdb1
mdadm: Cannot assemble mbr metadata on /dev/sdb
mdadm: Cannot assemble mbr metadata on /dev/sda1
mdadm: Cannot assemble mbr metadata on /dev/sda
mdadm: no recogniseable superblock on /dev/ram15
mdadm: no recogniseable superblock on /dev/ram14
mdadm: no recogniseable superblock on /dev/ram13
mdadm: no recogniseable superblock on /dev/ram12
mdadm: no recogniseable superblock on /dev/ram11
mdadm: no recogniseable superblock on /dev/ram10
mdadm: no recogniseable superblock on /dev/ram9
mdadm: no recogniseable superblock on /dev/ram8
mdadm: no recogniseable superblock on /dev/ram7
mdadm: no recogniseable superblock on /dev/ram6
mdadm: no recogniseable superblock on /dev/ram5
mdadm: no recogniseable superblock on /dev/ram4
mdadm: no recogniseable superblock on /dev/ram3
mdadm: no recogniseable superblock on /dev/ram2
mdadm: no recogniseable superblock on /dev/ram
mdadm: no recogniseable superblock on /dev/ram0
mdadm: No arrays found in config file or automatically
```

/dev/sda1 and /dev/sdc1 are 1TB disks which are RAID0

```
enes@emma:/dev$ sudo fdisk -l
Disk /dev/ram0: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram1: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram2: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram3: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram4: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram5: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram6: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram7: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram8: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram9: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram10: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram11: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram12: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram13: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram14: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram15: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/sda: 931,5 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x7d951651

Device     Boot Start        End    Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1          63 1953523119 1953523057 931,5G 42 SFS

Partition 1 does not start on physical sector boundary.


Disk /dev/sdb: 232,9 GiB, 250059350016 bytes, 488397168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x43ea7351

Device     Boot     Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1  *         2048    206847    204800   100M  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sdb2          206848 319700991 319494144 152,4G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sdb3       487473152 488394751    921600   450M 27 Hidden NTFS WinRE
/dev/sdb4       319700992 487473151 167772160    80G 83 Linux

Partition table entries are not in disk order.


Disk /dev/sdc: 931,5 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x7d951650

Device     Boot Start        End    Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sdc1          63 1953523119 1953523057 931,5G 42 SFS

Partition 1 does not start on physical sector boundary.


Disk /dev/sdd: 1,8 TiB, 2000365289472 bytes, 3906963456 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: F174ECE7-7BE9-48D1-B012-E092D24503AC

Device     Start        End    Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sdd1   2048 3906961407 3906959360  1,8T Microsoft basic data


Disk /dev/sde: 1,8 TiB, 2000365289472 bytes, 3906963456 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x975a0f26

Device     Boot Start        End    Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sde1        2048 3906963455 3906961408  1,8T  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT


Disk /dev/sdf: 1,8 TiB, 2000365289472 bytes, 3906963456 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: C430DF70-B1F6-4111-8C5A-3D43987D88BC

Device     Start        End    Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sdf1   2048 3906961407 3906959360  1,8T Microsoft basic data


Disk /dev/dm-0: 1,8 TiB, 2000404086784 bytes, 3907039232 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 65536 bytes / 131072 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x73736572

Device      Boot      Start        End    Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/dm-0p1      1920221984 3736432267 1816210284   866G 72 unknown
/dev/dm-0p2      1936028192 3889681299 1953653108 931,6G 6c unknown
/dev/dm-0p3               0          0          0     0B  0 Empty
/dev/dm-0p4        27722122   27722568        447 223,5K  0 Empty

Partition 1 does not start on physical sector boundary.
Partition 2 does not start on physical sector boundary.
Partition 4 does not start on physical sector boundary.
Partition table entries are not in disk order.
```

Comment: Here's a suggestion: Don't do that. As a general rule, the Windows system partition should **not** be accessed from the outside, from a live or dual booted OS, **especially when that partition resides in a (Windows) software RAID**.

Comment: It's not windows system partition? It's my storage disk, no OS installed on those disks. Just documents, movies, tv series, animes etc.

Comment: Better but most likely not accessible anyway. It's a Windows software RAID.

Comment: it's not a good idea to put data for storage on a striped volume backup the data, destroy the array and either use them as jbod or create a spanned volume in a filesystem that Linux can read.